# mysql count return multiple rows in DESC order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have read count only returns one row, however if you use group by you can get multiple rows returned as such

[image]

The code that returned the result above is

> SELECT event_id, COUNT( event_id ) AS nr FROM  `picks`  GROUP BY
>   event_id DESC  LIMIT 0 , 30

However I now need to find a way to order it by `DESC` order. I have tried `order by` but then I only get 1 row back and it looks like I cant use `DESC` with group by. Looking for advice

UPDATE

The following give me the result as displayed in image below

```
SELECT event_id, COUNT( event_id ) AS nr
FROM  picks
GROUP BY event_id
Order by event_id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Descending Order**

```
SELECT event_id, COUNT( event_id ) AS nr
FROM  picks
GROUP BY event_id
Order by event_id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image]

**Ascending Order**  *//This is the default sort order*

```
SELECT event_id, COUNT( event_id ) AS nr
FROM  picks
GROUP BY event_id
Order by event_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image]

Comment: is it the event_id you want to sort desc or the count?